# SQL find words in string, sort result by number of words found

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a coding problem and was wondering if there is a SQL implementation of the following scenario:

I want to search in a text column for certain words and want to sort the results based on the number of individual words found. For example:

Let's find the row which contains: a b s

```
a b b c d e s
b d s w d a s
x d s g w d s
f e h w d s a
```

The desired result would be:

```
a b b c d e s (it contains all 3 words)
b d s w d a s (it contains all 3 words)
f e h w d s a (it contains 2 words)
x d s g w d s (it contains 1 word)
```

Is it recommended doing something like this rather in e.g. PHP or is there an efficient SQL way to do so?

Comment: Yes. No. But you can. Take a look at regular expressions.

Comment: @Tom . . . Is this one column or multiple columns?

Comment: Try full text search, see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: @GordonLinoff just one column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using boolean expressions:

```
select t.*,
       ( (col like '%a%') +
         (col like '%b%') +
         (col like '%s%') +
       ) as num_matches
from t
order by num_matches desc;
```

If words should be separated by spaces, then:

```
select t.*,
       ( (concat(' ', col, ' ') like '% a %') +
         (concat(' ', col, ' ') like '% b %') +
         (concat(' ', col, ' ') like '% s %') +
       ) as num_matches
from t
order by num_matches desc;
```

Finally, if you have this type of problem, then you should do one of two things:

- If the text really is text, then look into full text search capabilities.
- If the text is really a list of something like keywords or users, then fix your data model and use a junction/association table.

Comment: thanks - works exactly as expected.  Also great idea with the spaces between the words!

Answer (score 0):

If done within SQL, I would look at doing it using full text search which allows for RANK(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879245.aspx)

Comment: No - SQL Server / SQL Azure only. Didn't see in question that they were using MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

My idea:

1. convert to distinct words list using solution: [SQL split values to multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942508/sql-split-values-to-multiple-rows)
2. count found rows for every original row.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm newbie on stackoverflow. Why should comment not answer?
I can see caption: "Comments are used to ask for clarification or to point out problems in the post." My text is ask or clarification?

Comment: more or less like "This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether. "

Comment: Ok, I understand - my solution is not enough detailed.